# Retornar string contendo somente consoantes

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Preciso elaborar um regex para pegar somente consoantes de uma string.

Hoje apenas sei como tratar para tirar os caracteres não-alfanuméricos, mas tentei de alguns modos a inserir mais um grupo para retirar as vogais e não deu certo, segue o código:

```
import re

class TesteRegex:

    def trata_string( value ):
                  
        teste = re.sub(r'[\W_]','',value.upper(), flags=re.IGNORECASE)

        return teste
        
    nome = "T3ste@_test@and000_  t3ste"

    teste = trata_string(nome)

    print(teste)
```

Como poderia adicionar o conjunto `[aeiou]` a essa estrutura?

Comment: Tem que ser feito exclusivamente com Regex ou pode ser usadas a particularidades da linguagem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Não precisa de regex

Se quer manter somente as consoantes (considerando que são apenas os caracteres ASCII, ou seja, nada de caracteres como "ñ", "ÿ", etc), bastaria fazer algo do tipo:

```py
nome = "T3ste@_test@and000_  t3ste"
vogais = 'aeiouAEIOU'
print(''.join(c for c in nome if (('a' <= c <= 'z') or ('A' <= c <= 'Z')) and c not in vogais))
```

Usei uma [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) que percorre os caracteres da string e pega somente as consoantes (eu vejo se é uma letra de "A" a "Z" e se não é vogal). Depois junto todas em uma única string, usando `join`.

Nesse caso, o resultado será `Tsttstndtst` (somente as consoantes da string).

Ou, em vez de ter uma variável com as vogais e ver se a letra não é uma delas, faça o contrário, crie uma variável contendo todas as consoantes, e para cada letra da string você verifica se ela é uma delas:

```py
consoantes = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ'
nome = "T3ste@_test@and000_  t3ste"
print(''.join(c for c in nome if c in consoantes))
```

Desta forma eu nem preciso verificar se é letra (se não for consoante, tanto faz se é letra ou não, pois não será incluído no resultado final).

---

Se quiser, pode usar uma função geradora que retorna somente as consoantes, e aí você usa-a no `join`:

```py
def get_consoantes(s):
    consoantes = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ'
    for c in s:
        # se é consoante
        if c in consoantes:
            yield c

print(''.join(get_consoantes(nome))) # Tsttstndtst
```

---

Ao fazer `c in consoantes`, estamos fazendo uma busca linear na string `consoantes`. Mas se forem feitas muitas buscas, uma pequena otimização que pode ser feita é usar `set`:

```py
consoantes = set('bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ')
print(''.join(c for c in nome if c in consoantes))
```

A busca em um `set` tem tempo constante (ver [aqui](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)), por isso assim fica mais otimizado do que se buscássemos em uma string (veja comparação no final).

---

#### Mas se quiser muito usar regex...

Acho que a solução acima fica bem mais simples. Com regex ficaria, na minha opinião, mais complicado:

```py
import re

r = re.compile('[^b-df-hj-np-t-v-z]', re.I)
nome = "T3ste@_test@and000_  t3ste"
print(r.sub('', nome)) # Tsttstndtst
```

Eu usei uma [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) para pegar tudo que **não** é consoante (tudo que está entre `[^` e `]` é negado pela regex). E lá dentro coloquei os intervalos para indicar as letras que não quero: `b-d` são as letras entre "b" e "d", `j-n` são as letras entre "j" e "n", etc. E usei a *flag* `re.I`, que ignora a diferença entre maiúsculas e minúsculas. Ou seja, esta regex pega qualquer letra que não seja uma consoante. Por fim, uso `sub` para trocar tudo isso por `''` (string vazia), que no fim é o mesmo que removê-las.

Usar `\W`, como está no seu código, não funciona bem, porque assim você vai manter também os dígitos e o caractere `_`, mas como você disse que quer somente as consoantes, então `\W` não é uma boa opção (e tentar arrumar isso com outra regex então, é pior ainda; se for mesmo para usar regex, use uma só que vai direto ao ponto).

---

Em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/527679/112052) foi sugerido o uso de [intersecções entre classes de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclassintersect.html), mas o [módulo `re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) nativo do Python **não** suporta este recurso (até a versão atual, que é 3.9; pode ser que no futuro mude, mas por enquanto não dá para usar).

Se quiser usar este recurso, atualmente a opção é instalar o [módulo `regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/):

```py
# ATENÇÃO: módulo externo, deve ser instalado com pip: https://pypi.org/project/regex
import regex

r = regex.compile('[^a-z&&[^aeiou]]', regex.IGNORECASE | regex.VERSION1)
print(r.sub('', nome))
```

No caso, o trecho `a-z&&[^aeiou]` são todas as letras de "a" a "z", exceto as vogais (ou seja, somente as consoantes). E o `[^` no início nega esses caracteres, portanto a regex pega tudo que não for consoante.

---

Ainda sim, acho que não precisa de regex. As primeiras soluções acima são, na minha opinião, muito mais simples e claras.

Só como curiosidade, segue um comparativo das soluções, usando o [módulo `timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) para medir os tempos:

```py
from timeit import timeit
import re

consoantes_string = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ'
consoantes_set = set('bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ')
r = re.compile('[^b-df-hj-np-t-v-z]', re.I)
nome = "T3ste@_test@and000_  t3ste"

# executa 1 milhão de vezes cada teste
params = { 'number' : 1000000, 'globals': globals() }

# imprime os tempos em segundos
print(timeit("''.join(c for c in nome if c in consoantes_set)", **params))
print(timeit("''.join(c for c in nome if c in consoantes_string)", **params))
print(timeit("r.sub('', nome)", **params))
```

Os tempos são impressos em segundos, e podem variar de uma máquina para outra. Na minha o resultado foi:

```
1.3250721090007573
1.4059548949999225
3.3496847289998186
```

Ou seja, com `set` ficou ligeiramente mais rápido do que se usar uma string com as consoantes, enquanto que a regex ficou quase 3 vezes mais lenta.

Claro que para strings pequenas sendo processadas poucas vezes a diferença será insignificante, mas este é mais um motivo para não preferir regex. Com `for` e `if` o código fica - na minha opinião - mais simples e claro de entender e manter, e ainda tem o bônus de ser mais rápido. Regex pode até ser legal, mas [nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Answer (score 2):

Também penso que não há a necessidade de usar regex aqui.

De maneira mais simplificada e generalista, aqui vai uma função que, ao receber um string `entrada` e um string de `caracteres_para_filtrar`, retorna o string `entrada` sem os caracteres presentes em `caracteres_para_filtrar`:

```
def filtrar_string(entrada: str, caracteres_para_filtrar: str):
    saida = ""
    for caractere in entrada:
        if caractere not in caracteres_para_filtrar:
            saida = saida + caractere
    return saida
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
meu_string = "Olá Mundo!"
filtro = "OM"
meu_string_filtrado = filtrar_string(meu_string, filtro)
print(meu_string_filtrado)  # output: "lá undo!"
```

Portanto, basta chamar esta função passando como `entrada` o seu string, e `caracteres_para_filtrar` como um string contendo todas as vogais (`"aeiouAEIOU"`).

Se preferir, aqui está uma versão da função que utiliza uma compreensão de lista no lugar do for loop explícito:

```
def filtrar_string(entrada: str, caracteres_para_filtrar: str):
    return "".join([
        caractere 
        for caractere in entrada 
        if caractere not in caracteres_para_filtrar
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

você pode usar `[a-z&&[^aeiou]]`. Nesse caso a-z são todas as letras de a até z, o && representa a interseção, então você tem todas as letras que não são `aeiou`

Comment: Poderia exemplificar? me seria útil também. serve só em re.sub, replace não?

Comment: @GabrielMendes Este recurso não é suportado nativamente pelo módulo `re` do Python (embora dê para usar com módulos externos). De qualquer forma, acho que nem precisa de regex, conforme explicado na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/527703/112052) :-)