# Programa para contar quantas consoantes possui em uma lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, loop, if, lógica

O exercício que pede para ler 10 caracteres e inseri-los em uma lista, após isso, criar uma função para contar quantas consoantes a lista possui.

```
n_char = int(input("Informe o numero caracteres: "))
lista_char = []

for i in range (0,n_char):
    caracteres = str(input(f"Insira o {i+1} caractere: "))
    lista_char.append(caracteres)
print("Lista de caracteres: ",lista_char)

def conta_consoante(lista_char):
    soma = 0
    for i in lista_char:
        if i == 'a' or i == 'e' or i == 'i' or i == 'o'or i == 'u':
            soma = 0
        else:
            soma += 1
    print("Soma de consoantes: ",soma)
    return soma

conta_consoante(lista_char)
```

Porém não sei o que está acontecendo, dependendo do caractere que eu coloque, ele considera como uma vogal e não como consoante.
Se eu informar 10 caracteres, sendo eles `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l]` o programa conta apenas uma consoante.
O que eu estou errando ?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/527674/112052

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema já foi apontado em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/551142/112052) (você zera a soma sempre que encontra uma vogal), mas ainda tem outros problemas.

Você está pedindo que o usuário digite algo, mas **nada** garante que ele vai digitar somente uma letra (ele pode digitar "abcxyz", por exemplo). Aliás, você não tem sequer a garantia de que será digitada uma letra de fato (pois podem ser digitados números, espaço, pontuação, emojis, etc). E seu código vai contar tudo isso como consoantes, afinal, a sua lógica é "se não for vogal, incrementa o contador". Mas se um caractere não é vogal, não significa necessariamente que será uma consoante.

Claro que se forem digitadas somente letras, aí funcionaria, mas como é o usuário que vai digitar os dados, então pode vir qualquer coisa, e você não pode contar com a sorte de que só serão digitadas letras. E na verdade, até mesmo vogais maiúsculas serão contabilizadas como consoantes, pois você só testa as minúsculas.

Então uma forma melhor seria ter uma lista de consoantes:

```py
def conta_consoante(caracteres):
    consoantes = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'
    consoantes = set(consoantes + consoantes.upper()) # incluir maiúsculas e minúsculas
    soma = 0
    for i in caracteres:
        if i in consoantes:
            soma += 1
    return soma
```

Usei um `set` para guardar as consoantes, pois ele é mais otimizado para buscas. Assim, para cada caractere eu verifico se ele é uma das consoantes e incremento o contador.

Outra forma de construir o conjunto de consoantes é usar o módulo `string`:

```py
from string import ascii_letters # já tem todas as letras

def conta_consoante(caracteres):
    # pego todas as letras e removo as vogais
    consoantes = set(ascii_letters) - set('aeiouAEIOU')
    soma = 0
    for i in caracteres:
        if i in consoantes:
            soma += 1
    return soma
```

E caso tenha alguma consoantes acentuada (como por exemplo `ñ`, que não é usado em português, mas em nenhum momento foi dito que deveria ser restrito a isso), basta normalizar a string antes:

```py
from string import ascii_letters
from unicodedata import normalize

def conta_consoante(caracteres):
    consoantes = set(ascii_letters) - set('aeiouAEIOU')
    soma = 0
    for c in caracteres:
        for i in normalize('NFD', c):
            if i in consoantes:
                soma += 1
    return soma
```

Assim consoantes como `ñ` serão contabilizadas corretamente.

Talvez já fuja demais do escopo da pergunta, mas enfim, se quiser entender melhor o que normalização faz, leia [aqui](/q/406545/112052), [aqui](/a/396555/112052) e [aqui](/a/345946/112052).

Comment: Sensacional. De fato me prendi muito ao que a questão queria e acabei não pensando nesses fatores que você mencionou. Ambos seus códigos me mostraram coisas que eu sequer sabia que existia em python. Agradeço pelas orientações e pelas dicas.

Answer (score 1):

Sua função `conta_consoante()` não foi escrita da melhor forma. Sua função zera `soma` toda vez que ele encontra uma vogal e o método de classificação de caracteres é prolixo.

Uma possibilidade de melhorar sua função é melhorando a classificação de caracteres usando o operador `in` que verifica se um elemento está contido em uma sequencia:

```
def conta_consoante(lista_char):
    soma = 0
    for i in lista_char:
        if i not in "aeiouAEIOU":            
            soma += 1
    return soma

s = ['a','b','c','n','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l']

print(f"Em {s}  são {conta_consoante(s)} consoantes.")
#Em ['a', 'b', 'c', 'n', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']  são 9 consoantes.
```

Mas como já dito caso o usuário entre com coisas que não sejam letras o programa apresentará falsos resultados.

Uma solução real seria é filtrar a entrada do usuário e descartar tudo aquilo que não seja exatamente uma consoante: letras, números, emojis, grupos,.....seja o que for se não é exatamente uma consoante é descartado e contar o que sobrar.
Para isso pode ser usada a função builtin [`filter(função, iteravel)`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#filter) que obtém um iterador a partir dos elementos de um iteravel para os quais a função retorna `True`. No caso nossa [função anônima](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/glossary.html#term-lambda) verifica se o elemento `e` da  `entrada` está contido no conjunto `consoantes`.  Para fazer a contagem dos elemento restantes após a filtragem é usada a função builtin [len()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#len).

```
from string import ascii_letters

consoantes = set(ascii_letters) - set('aeiouAEIOU')

def conta_consoante(entrada):
  return len(list(filter(lambda e: e in consoantes, entrada)))

s = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l']

print(f"Em {s}  são {conta_consoante(s)} consoantes.")
#Em ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']  são 9 consoantes.
```

Como bem lembrado nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/551160/137387) consoantes acentuadas também podem podem ser contadas a trazendo para sua [forma normal D](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) por exemplo:
O caractere `Ç UNICODE U+00C7 (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA)` pode ser decomposto em `C UNICODE U+0043 (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C) ' UNICODE U+0327 (COMBINING CEDILLA)`. Então existem duas formas normais para caracteres Unicode:

- `Ç UNICODE U+00C7 (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA)` é a forma normal C.
- `C UNICODE U+0043 (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C) ' UNICODE U+0327 (COMBINING CEDILLA)` é forma normal D.

No caso usaremos na filtragem apenas o primeiro caractere da forma normal D.

```
from string import ascii_letters
from unicodedata  import normalize

consoantes = set(ascii_letters) - set('aeiouAEIOU')

def conta_consoante(entrada):
  return len(list(filter(lambda e: normalize('NFD', e)[0] in consoantes, entrada)))

s = ['a','b','c','ñ','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l']

print(f"Em {s}  são {conta_consoante(s)} consoantes.")
#Em ['a', 'b', 'c', 'ñ', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']  são 9 consoantes.
```

Answer (score 0):

No seu código você está zerando a variavel soma toda vez que ele encontra uma vogal:

```
if i == 'a' or i == 'e' or i == 'i' or i == 'o'or i == 'u':
        soma = 0
```

O correto é só deixar passar caso ele encontre a vogal, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
for i in lista_char:
            if i == 'a' or i == 'e' or i == 'i' or i == 'o'or i == 'u':
                continue
            else:
                soma += 1
```

Comment: Verdade, acabei de ver aqui o meu erro.
Obrigado amigo

Answer (score -2):

```
lista = ['b','a','t','p','o','i','f','e','h','g','p']
count = 0

def consoante(param):
    vogais = ['a','e','i','o','u']
    if param not in vogais:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

for i in lista:
    count += consoante(i)

print("Total: {} consoantes".format(count))
```